# filter the service based on check boxes in angularjs with different routings but same controller and same page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have two controllers

1. buildersCtrl --->listpagefilter.html
2. filtersCtrl  ---->filter.html

view :

[image]

so my page routing is like this

```
sidemenu.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
                .when('/builders/:id', {
                    templateUrl: '../template/listpagefilter.html',
                    controller: 'buildersCtrl'
                })
});
```

Up to this everything is working fine,but my problem when i click on checkbox on box (1bhk or 2bhk) based on that URL has to be generated 
for example here I clicked on 1 bhk check box in filters controller
it has to be generated 
url like this :

```
my requirement :
 checked on check boxes:

 1st page url:ip:port/#/builders/1 
  clicked on check box 1bhk: url:ip:port/#/builders/1/?bedrooms=0
  and clicked on check box 2bhk: url:ip:port/#/builders/1/?bedrooms=0,1

un checked on check boxes:
 1st page url:ip:port/#/builders/1 
  unchecked only in check box 1bhk: url:ip:port/#/builders/1/bedrooms=1
```

my filters controller code :

```
 sidemenu.controller('filtersCtrl',['$scope','$rootScope','allServices','$window','$routeParams','$location',function (a,b,e,w,r,l) {


    a.unitnames = [{
        id:0,name: "1 BHK",selected:false
    },{
        id:1,name: "2 BHK",selected:false
    }, {
        id:2,name: "3 BHK",selected:false
    }, {
        id:3,name: "4 BHK",selected:false
    }];


    a.OnItemClick=function (bedroom) {

    if(bedroom.id==0){
        alert(bedroom.selected);
        l.path("/builders/"+r.id).search({bedrooms:bedroom.id})

    }
}

}]);
```

my filters html page code :

```
<li uib-dropdown>
                            <a uib-dropdown-toggle>BHK<span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul uib-dropdown-menu>
                                <li ng-repeat="unitType in unitnames" >
                                    <label class="control control--checkbox" ng-click="OnItemClick(unitType)">
                                        {{unitType.name}}
                                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="unitType.selected">
                                        <div class="control__indicator"></div>
                                    </label>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
```

my problem when checked/unchecked based on that how to change the url (adding or removing dynamically)

may be my problem can solved like this

```
<li class="checkboxInfo ng-scope" data-ng-repeat="option in filter.options" data-ng-class="{'active': option.selected || option.selectedFromUrl, 'disable':option.disabled || option.disabledFromUrl}" data-ng-click="filterChanged(option, $event)">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add and remove the bedroom ids as they are checked or unchecked.

```
var bedroomsIds = [];
a.OnItemClick=function (bedroom) {

 if(bedroomsIds.indexOf(bedroom) < 0){
  bedroomsIds.push(bedroom)
}
else{
    bedroomsIds.splice(bedroomsIds.indexOf(bedroom), 1);
    }
    l.path("/builders/"+r.id).search({bedrooms:bedroomsIds.join(", ")})

}
```

Comment: The bedroomIds will have the list of checked BHK

Comment: only checked boxes  is pushing in bedroomIds  but based on urls is not generating like bedrooms=1,2,3 its overriding